# how to integrate opentok in android mobile application?

Tags: android, opentok

I have integrated video chat using Opentok and it works really well but the issue I'm facing now is that it will work only if both of us open up the app. What the requirement is that we should be able to make video call even if the other user has not opened up the app. Please help me in this and thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "user has not opened up the app"?What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: when app in two mobile open then only  its working , so that i need to call particular user/ member to call for vedio chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need a Service which is controlling the connection running in the background which generates its own `Thread()` to perform and mantain the `Server` connection.

If you want the service to be "unkillable" use the `START_STICKY` variable at the start of the service.

Keep this alive by requesting WAKE_LOCK

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyWakelockTag"); 
wakeLock.acquire();
```

And include the permission

```
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

Then, have the Service Start the Main Activity for viewing a connection. 
You can do this through the Intent Service with`startActivityForResult` and just make sure you get that the connection was correctly started up on the view or if already bound to the activity pass over the correct veriables/parceables/etc. Just remember to do effective management using the onPause

It's some re-writing, but not too bad. Good example code for this can be found in the [CSIPSimple](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) application code.

Comment: i did not understand complitly . because i am new to these concepts ..please guide me it with some explanation